# Reaper GUI dissapearing

Tags: daw

I managed to remove the bar with all the play, loop and stop buttons as well as the time signature and playback rate slider on. How can I get it back? I've tried all of the options under view.

The bar appears just above the mixer which is at the bottom of the window.

Comment: I am certain that Reaper has a user discussion forum. You should post your question there because it is full of Reaper experts. There are not many people who use Reaper on this site.

Comment: @WheatWilliams I agree the Reaper forum is better than here for this. At the same time, the question of whether software support is on topic seems to have been asked and answered on meta: http://meta.music.stackexchange.com/questions/2365/music-software-should-we-engage-in-general-troubleshooting

Comment: I have already asked it on the reaper forums and got an answer, sorry for posting it unnecessarily here. I didn't know where to ask it.

Comment: @DanielCann If you copy and paste the answer here, you can answer your own question and add to the knowledge here, plus maybe get some extra rep for it.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the view back by clicking:

- View > Transport